# "security policy error" on iPhone and iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, security, ipod-touch, policy

I'm getting an "Error from Debugger: Error launching remote program: security policy error" when I try to run my app on my ipod touch.  The provisions look in order, and the app builds to my iphone 3gs just fine.  The app used to build just fine to my ipod touch, so I'm flustered what could have changed and wondering if anyone has any thoughts on what might be causing this issue.  The build logs are below.

```
Mon Mar 15 14:25:54 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[449] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Mon Mar 15 14:25:55 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Unable to launch com.yourcompany.Unearthed because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.
Mon Mar 15 14:25:55 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[449] <Error>: error: unable to launch the application with CFBundleIdentifier 'com.yourcompany.Unearthed' sbs_error = 9
Mon Mar 15 14:25:55 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[449] <Warning>: 1 [01c1/0903]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: ''
Mon Mar 15 14:25:55 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[449] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process (null): security policy error
Mon Mar 15 14:26:03 unknown MobileSafari[72] <Warning>: void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: UITrackingRunLoopMode
```

Comment: Some extra info: my adhoc build for that device works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you checked that the iPod doesn't contain any expired provisioning profiles? I've had trouble in the past when building to devices that contain expired provisioning profiles.

Try removing any expired profiles and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all old expire provisioning profile..

Answer (score 0):

We "fixed" this by installing the release version (built for ad-hoc distribution) and then debugging from Xcode. It installs and updates the application fine from now. 3GS with 4.3.2.