# security policy error

Tags: iphone

Before one month I have created one provisioning profile for an application. So many time I have installed that application in my device.

Yesterday I have tried to install the same application. But I am getting some issues I have mention below:

Error launching remote program: security policy error.
Error launching remote program: security policy error.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.

I have recreated provisioning profile. But no use.

Main issues is previously I have installed so many application using the same provisioning profile. From yesterday those are not working.

But that provisioning profile will expire on 1/10/2011.

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197349/why-do-i-get-a-security-policy-error-when-launching-my-iphone-os-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any expired profiles on your device :

**Settings** -> **General** -> **Profiles** -> (look for any expired profiles and delete them).

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake. I have removed 3 expired profiles from iPhone device. Now it is working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: One has to wonder, why doesn't XCode just ignore expired profiles.  ...oh yeah, its Apple.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, had distribution in as release in the Build Locations by mistake, this also generates this error when building for release.